# Редирект с одной папки на другую

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess, редирект

Пользователь имеет возможность добавления доменов. После того как пользователь добавил домен, он выбирает какой дизайн прикрепить к добавленному домену. Чтобы мне не создавать множество однотипных файлов(готовых дизайнов) для каждого домена, я собираюсь сделать следующее: юзер добавил домен, создал ссылку на домен вида домен.ру/квартиры. система в свою очередь добавила я так понимаю новую запись в htaccess о том чтобы был редирект с урла домен.ру/квартиры на папку дизайн_квартиры/index.html без смены адреса. Реализовывал ранее с помощью доменных указателей, но в таком случае пользователь может создать на один добавленный домен - один доменный указатель, что весьма ограничивает. Если возможно сделать задуманную мной мысль, подскажите что необходимо.

Попытался реализовать так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/apartment
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../apart_desgin/ [L]
```

но сделать редирект на уровень выше я так понял он не может т.е. в папке www есть папки домен_пользователя.ру и папка "квартиры_дизайн". нужен редирект с 1ой во 2ую без смены url

Comment: Зачем это делать через редирект, если это обычный [маппинг роута](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html) (пути) на папку?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov да действительно ваше решение помогло. Но, мне нужно открыть страницу находящуюся в папке другого сайта, без смены url

Comment: Если сайты на вашем сервере, то можно делать маппинг на их директории, но если вовне, то тогда остается только то что вы написали в вопросе. Опять же есть ньансы вроде доступности папок для веб-серверов.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, понял. На сервере все, но что то не хочет их открывать. Я правильно понял, что нужно в папке домена создать .htaccess вставить строку `DirectoryIndex ../нужная_папка/index.html`?

Comment: Лучше прописать полный путь, хотя как хотите.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, видимо хостинг не дает такую возможность, так как корнем является папка сайта, за ее пределы выйти не дает, соответственно и полный путь прописать не получится

Answer (score 0):

Самый доступный вариант - сделать это PHP скриптом. Если вы создаете множество доменов 3-го уровня например, но для всех задаете единый корневой каталог, то в едином входном файле типа index.php вы можете проверять, с каким доменным именем вошел посетитель, а на основании этих данных уже можете переводить его в любой подкаталог.